# Guzzle http request to nodejs server connection refuse

Tags: node.js, express, laravel-5, guzzle

My Laravel PHP code is running inside vagrant homestead. Here is my PHP function that is going to send the http request to nodejs server.

```
private function sendcampaign($data) 
    {

        $client = new Client();

        $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/sendcampaign', ['json' => $data]);

        $response = $res->getBody();

        if($res->getStatusCode() == 200) 
        {

            Log::info($response);

        } else {

            Log::error($response);

        }
    }
```

My NodeJS server is running independently. I run it using this command `nmp start`. Here is the code to my nodejs server that is accepting the request

```
app.post("/sendcampaign", function(request, response) {
  if (request.body) {

    var campaign = JSON.stringify(request.body);

    response.status(200);
    response.send({
      status: "success",
      message: "Campaign sent successfully."
    });

  } else {
    response.status(404);
    response.send({ status: "error", message: "Campaign failed." });
  }

  return;
});
```

However when I run it, I always getting an error

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

But I already tried it in Postman the response is

```
{"status":"success","message":"Campaign sent successfully."}
```

I don't know what's the error on my PHP code using GuzzleHttp. Maybe I need to add some header options? What header options should I add? Can you help me?

Comment: Is this a docker +laravel  project?

Comment: @NetEmmanuel It is running inside Vagrant Homestead

Comment: @NetEmmanuel the NodeJS server is running independently.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `http://127.0.0.1:8080` with something like `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: @NetEmmanuel I just tried it. The same error.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Vagrant Homestead but I had this same issue with docker and I resolved it by inspecting my container for my docker IP I replaced `http://127.0.0.1:8080` with `http://my-docker-ip:8080`

Comment: OK maybe there's some configuration that I need to do inside vagrant. Thanks @NetEmmanuel.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are simply trying to save a json in Laravel you don't need to do it this way. Try this
```
 $client = new Client();
       $client->fill($data);
        $client->save()
```

Comment: The case is we need to POST the request to nodejs server because nodejs server is going to send it to another services. Not saving to the database

Comment: Oh, I see, try my previous suggestion. Good luck.